Why is my entire commit history showing up in all my pull requests?
I've been working on an opensource project and have run into a weird issue where all the pull requests I send contain all the changes I've made in previous pull requests on different branches.  The owner of the project has been getting frustrated asking me to please only create PRs for the files I actually worked on in each branch I create..... which I was doing all along.  When I looked I saw that all my PRs had around 100 changes and they were all the same files.
Seeing that he merged most of my changes and created a new version release which I pulled into my main branch I decided to just delete all my local branches as well as the remote branches I created and just continue with a clean slate re doing the last few changes I made since the update.  The next steps I took went as follows
git branch package_update
git switch package_update

The point of this branch is to remove packages no longer needed in the project so after making and saving the changes I did
git add package.json gatsby-config.json yarn.lock
git commit -m "remove unused packages"
git push --set-upstream origin package_update 

That created a package_update branch on the remote repo with my changes and I made a pull request.  Afterwards I merged it locally to my main branch by doing
git switch main
git merge package_update

From there I moved on to another feature by doing
git branch home_page
git switch home_page

I made the changes I needed to make then did
git add pages/HomePage.js
git commit -m "remove exclamation marks"
git push --set-upstream origin home_page

Then from there I went and made a pull request for those changes which is when I noticed there were two commits in that PR.  When I looked I saw the commit for the package_update branch as well as the commit for the home_page branch.  I make atomic commits as well so those are going to add up pretty quick.  He wasn't merging my pull requests before because he couldn't see what changes I had made due to them being buried in 100 prior commits.  He said he hasn't encountered that with anybody contributing to any of his other projects so I'm wondering what it is I'm doing to create this issue.  Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can stop this from happening?
